# How to check via the Wand binding whether a color string is valid in ImageMagick?

Tags: colors, imagemagick, wand

In [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org), the Python binding for [ImageMagick](https://legacy.imagemagick.org) I can use color names to create a plain image. For example:

```
img = Image(width=100, height=50, pseudo=f'xc:yellow')
```

In the example the string `yellow` has to be an [ImageMagick color string](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php). How can I test beforehand via a Wand method whether the color string is indeed recognized by ImageMagick?

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate a [Color object](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/wand/color.html#wand.color.Color) with your color string, you get an `ValueError` exception when the string is not valid. For example:

```
from wand.color import Color

col = Color('graay')
```

will raise a ValueError with the message "Unrecognized color string "'graay'".

So you can check for this:

```
try:
    col = Color('graay')
except ValueError as e:
    print("Don't know about this color")
```